# Getting error run sudo apt-get upgrade on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

```
setting xserver-xorg-legacy/xwrapper/allowed_users from configuration file
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libqt5webkit5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsamplerate0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsane-hpaio:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'policykit-desktop-privileges' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

How to fix ?
i'm trying to remove the package but not able to remove .

Comment: Please don't forget [today is the last day of *standard support* for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/), so consider upgrading asap unless you plan to use ESM (which is off-topic here)

Answer (score 0):

You have to trick over this problem. Remove the problematic file-list, reinstall the package by:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/policykit-desktop-privileges.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall policykit-desktop-privileges
```

then fix three other mentioned packages by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libqt5webkit5:amd64
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libsamplerate0:amd64 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libsane-hpaio:amd64
```

then install all upgrades for current release

```
sudo apt-get upgrade # upgrade packages
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # upgrade packages with all new dependencies
```

and then consider upgrading to 18.04 LTS as was recommended in comments.